# Selecting Some Hashes From Set of Hashes Based On Value In Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, enumerable

### Overall Problem I'm Solving:

I'm pretty new to Ruby and working on creating a search method for my app in which the user searches for the name of one model, foo, which may have many instances of that name, and we return the results of all the related instances of another model, Day. However, each foo has multiple versions of day it is associated with (there are 4 different versions total it can be associated with. We display those versions through foo, and foo contains them in booleans: include_in_standard, include_in_v1, etc.).

I need my search method to let me know which versions foo is included for each day, so that I can display the search results accordingly. Also, only certain days are available to different kinds of users. I've gotten it so that I'm passing the information on the days and versions out of the model to the controller, however, in the controller, I'm having a problem getting only the days which are available to the current user.

### The Structure Of The Code:

In the model for Day, I have a search method which returns the following:

```
results={:result_case=>result_case, :days_set=>days_set, :term0=>term0, :term1=>term1}
```

result_case is an integer, term0 and term1 are strings.

days_set is a Set which is formed like so

```
days_set=Set.new
array_of_foo.each do |f|
  f.join_table_connecting_foo_and_days.days.each do |foo|
    days_set+={:day=>d, :standard=>f.include_in_standard, :v1=>f.include_in_v1, :v2=>f.include_in_v2, :v3=>f.include_in_v3, :v4=>f.include_in_v4}
  end
end
days_set
```

In my controller, I call the search method which returns results, and assign it to the local variable results in the controller.
I also have an array of all the days which are accessible to the current_user, available_days.

### The Micro-Goal:

I want to get a set or array which is just the hashes from days_set where the day is included in available_days. That is, if my days_set is currently

```
[{:day=>d1, :standard=>true, :v1=>false, :v2=>false, :v3=>true, :v4=>true},
  {:day=>d2, :standard=>false, :v1=>true, :v2=>false, :v3=>true, :v4=>false},
  {:day=>d3, :standard=>false, :v1=>false, :v2=>false, :v3=>true, :v4=>true},
  {:day=>d4, :standard=>true, :v1=>true, :v2=>true, :v3=>true, :v4=>true},
  {:day=>d5, :standard=>false, :v1=>false, :v2=>false, :v3=>true, :v4=>false},
  {:day=>d6, :standard=>true, :v1=>false, :v2=>true, :v3=>false, :v4=>true}]

available_days=[d1, d3, d4]
```

then I want

```
[{:day=>d1, :standard=>true, :v1=>false, :v2=>false, :v3=>true, :v4=>true},
  {:day=>d3, :standard=>false, :v1=>false, :v2=>false, :v3=>true, :v4=>true},
  {:day=>d4, :standard=>true, :v1=>true, :v2=>true, :v3=>true, :v4=>true}]
```

### The Error/Problem/Code That's Not Working:

I've tried looking for ideas on how to do this elsewhere, but I don't think I have the coding vocabulary to describe what I'm trying to do.

I thought this would work, but it is generating a *Can't convert Symbol to Integer* error on the line marked ** (which is not in the code.)

```
days_set=results[:days_set]
** new_days_set=days_set.keep_if{|day_hash| available_days.include? day_hash[:day]
```

### Questions:

1. How can I get the hashes in my days_set whose day is in available_days?
2. I've been running into this error, *Can't convert Symbol to Integer*, more than any other error, at least once a week, maybe more. I feel like this indicates some concept I'm not quite understanding. Can you tell me what that concept is so I can look for information on it and/or direct me to some information on it? I don't know what it's called that I'm looking for, which makes it hard to find it.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using a gem for `Set`? It's not a standard Ruby class.

Comment: @mbratch It's in the [Ruby Documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html), so I assumed it was a standard Ruby class.

Comment: Ah yes you're right. My irb gave me an error but I forgot to require the lib.

Comment: To the person who downvoted this, it would be really helpful if you also left a comment on why so that I could learn to ask better questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get your days subset:

```
new_days = days_set.select { |ds| available_days.include? ds[:day] }
```

This will give you an array. Or you can use `.to_set` on it to get a set:

```
new_days_set = (days_set.select { |ds| available_days.include? ds[:day] }).to_set
```

The "can't convert symbol to integer" error is occuring because somewhere you're probably trying to compare a symbol, such as `:day` to an integer value, such as `d1`. Or if `ds[:day]` (the value for key `:day` for hash element `ds`) is a symbol and your `available_days` array is an array of integers.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me. Your solution also gives me a "can't convert symbol to integer" error. I think maybe I don't quite understand how symbols and hashes relate. Shouldn't ds[:day] give me the id number of the day object which the hash ds's :day attribute maps to? Ie, since in the first hash, :day=>d1, shouldn't when iterating through the hashes on the first hash, ds[:day] return d1?

Comment: @Magelet interesting. When I mock up your scenario it works. But I am assigning integer values to `d1`, `d2`, etc. How are your values being set? A "symbol" is sort of like a constant string. It's just a tag for the hash element. You can say `:day => 3` or you can say `"day" => 3` and both will work in a hash. But, there must be something different between what you're doing and what I'm showing. If you have `:day => d1` for example, then `d1` is a variable that must represent a value of some kind. I'm using your test scenario given with `d1`, `d2`, etc. Does that example work for you in `irb`?

Comment: d1, d2, etc are objects of my Day model/class, not integers (although I would think that when I put the day in the day_set, see in the structure section of the question, where days_set is formed, that what is really being put in would the be id, which should be an integer?). I'll try it with integers in irb to see if that clarifies anything.

Comment: Thanks that info helps. Your original problem statement shows `:day => d` but I don't see `d` defined. I'm sure the issue is in this area. In your simplified example, if `d1`, etc are set to integers, it all works. So in your real life example, you have integers in one place, but symbols in another and they're being compared through `includes?` or other method.

Comment: I think I may have figured out what is happening. I'm getting my available days from an array of class bar. Bar has_many days, so it looks like the technique I'm using in mapping the bar objects to their days won't work, (available_bar.flat_map {|b| b.days}. At least, when I pick one day, b.days doesn't work. I'm going to have to look into the associations more, and figure out how to access that properly. I think that's the problem, that the available days array is wonky.

Comment: Thank you for taking so much time to help me figure out what was wrong. It turns out that in constructing the days set, I was trying to add in the hash representing the info for the day with += but it seems I needed to use <<. This seems to have been the big problem, because it was giving me an aray in the day set instead of a hash.

Comment: @Magelet I'm glad you sorted it out.